# Atomic Construct and Data dependency

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

Does an atomic construct of OpenMp support data dependent operations?

Like, I am working on an example where I have a local_sum variable and a global_sum variable.

Inside the parallel region, each thread calculates its own local_sum. Inside this parallel region, I then use

```
#pragma omp atomic update
 global_sum += local_sum
```

To update the global_sum in serial. When I print global_sum, I get "nan".
Why?

Note: I know I can do this with a critical construct

Comment: Critical and atomic are both the wrong way to do this. You should add a `reduction` clause to the parallel construct (`for` or `sectionns`), and then you don't need the local sum anymore.

Comment: While you should use a `reduction` clause as Victor said (it does the private sums etc internally), The `atomic update` construct should also work in principle. So something seems to be wrong with your code. But without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we can't help you with that. For examples of using the `atomic` construct, see the [official examples](https://www.openmp.org/wp-content/uploads/openmp-examples-4.5.0.pdf), section 6.4 (page 178ff). You can also find examples for the `reduction` clause in section 7.9 (page 233ff).

Comment: Did you initialize the variable correctly? Besides, `#pragma omp atomic update global_sum += local_sum` is not a valid directive nor a valid instruction (and it is certainly skipped by compilers which should report some warnings).

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for your response. The code is written well, yes it works. It just the way it code formated by Stack Overflow when I posted my question. It's not like I wrote it in this one line way.

Comment: @paleonix , thanks, I will try that. I am in the early lessons of this. So i was comparing the 2 constructs since I have so far only learnt about them. Do you have any idea why my solution does not work for the "atomic" construct? Don't mind the format of the "#pragma"  line posted above. I wrote it well in the code, it's just StackOver flow that put it in this way or I don't know how to attach or type code when typing a question

Comment: @Sibulele If you get "nan" as a printout, the most probable explanation is that this variable is uninitialized. Note that improper use of an OpenMP sharing attribute can also result in uninitailized variable (e.g use of `private` instead of `firstprivate`). Please understand that we cannot answer your question until you show us your code. I have edited your post to show you how to include the code. Please update your post and provide a [mre].

Comment: The are multiple ways of correctly formatting code on SO.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).